# Aggregating data in R based on the contents of various columns

Tags: r, pivot-table, data-transform

I have some data like so, that I have loaded into R

```
Data column 1, Data column 2,option1, option2, option 3.
23,            45.6         ,       ,option2, option3
5,             30.6         ,option1,option2,
2,            5             ,       ,, option3
3,            40            ,       ,option2,
```

I want to expand the data so the the option columns become row entries and the data columns are duplicated for each option so I can then do a pivot table based on the column with the options in it

so, I want to know how to go from the top table of data to the bottom table of data in R

```
Data column 1, Data column 2,option
23,            45.6         ,option2, 
23,            45.6         ,option3
5,             30.6         ,option1
5,             30.6         ,option2
2,            5             ,option3
3,            40            ,option2
```

Comment: Can you please use `dput` to show the example so that we get the structure of the data correctly. thanks.  The column s names are also not clear for options.Yoou can try `df1 %>% separate_rows(optioncol, sep=",\\s*")`

Answer (score 0):

The way you've formatted your data is a problem; I'm modifying it a little.

```
@library(tidyverse)
# Your data structure is something like this:
df <- tibble(DataCol1 = c(23,5,2,3),
       DataCol2 = c(45.6, 30.6, 5, 40), 
       Option1 = c(NA, TRUE, NA, NA),
       Option2 = c(TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE),
       Option3 = c(TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA))
columnames = c("Option1", "Option2", "Option3")
```

We'll use `gather` to get the output you want

```
df %>% 
   # A row id makes it easier to put the data back in the same order it came in.
  rowid_to_column("ID") %>% 
    # Here's the tricky part.
  gather(key = "Options", val = "val", all_of(columnames) ) %>% 
    # Clean up a little.
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>% 
  arrange(ID) %>% 
  select(- ID, -val)
```

And the result is

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  DataCol1 DataCol2 Options
     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  
1       23     45.6 Option2
2       23     45.6 Option3
3        5     30.6 Option1
4        5     30.6 Option2
5        2      5   Option3
6        3     40   Option2
```

The thoroughly modern way to do this is with `pivot_longer`.  Sadly, that release hasn't been installed on my system.  You can read Hadley Wickham's instructions for it at https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#pivoting

Now that we've handled that.  For your *next* question, Please make a Minimal Reproducible Example.  See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) .  You'll get more help quicker if you do!

Comment: that works but the columns i want to use, in real life, have no common prefix,
they are

headings <-  df[0,c(seq(37,52,1))]

Comment: I've tried the following based on your suggestion:

df%>% 
  pivot_longer(all_of(selectedheadings), names_to = "headings", values_to = "headiungchosen")


but I get an error:



Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `data.frame<


with some columns reporting data type  character and others reporting datatype logical

Comment: I get the same error if I substitute 
starts_with("Opt")
with
all_of(selectedheadings)

Comment: I'm using
headings<-  df[0,c(seq(37,52,1))]

to get the column names and every time I unlist either it of one of it's entries I get chaacter(0) dispite having a string when I print it as a list berfore calling unlist

Comment: whenever I try to view thew headings e.g view(headings) I get thge following error which I cannot find reporterd anywher else: Error in view_fun(list( Data In Heading = character(0), : invalid 'x' argument

Comment: I've got it sorted now, i had to change the way I was getting the column namews to headings <-  colnames(df)[37:52]

Comment: if you modify your anser to include

columnnames = c("Option1", "Option2", "Option3")

at the top and then change the following line
gather(key = "Options", val = "val", starts_with("Opt")) %>% 
to
gather(key = "Options", val = "val", all_of(columnnames )) %>% 


I'll consider jobs a gooden and close

Comment: OK, I did that.  Looks good?

Comment: I've just spotted that it creates a row of data for each named column always and no only if it appears on the row

Comment: I can't find a reference to your original startsWith syntax, is it possible to combine startsWith with the list of colunms/valujes columnnames so that only those data entries that startWith one of them are included and all the blank entries get dropped.

Comment: I think I'm going to writye a for loop to get past this emapass

Comment: It was `starts_with`.  See https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#select .
I regret that , after building you a solution that works on the data you posted, you feel that you cannot upvote my work because of some additional requirements.